# How to adapt titlespacing to odd or even pages

Tags: titlesec, ifthenelse

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{report}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{}{\chaptername}{-2pt}{\hskip5cm \centering \Huge \bfseries \mbox}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{-112pt}{27pt}

\begin{document}
\chapter{test}
blablabla
\end{document}
```

How am I able to have `\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{-112pt}{27pt}` on even pages, and `\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{-112pt}{27pt}` on odd pages?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thank you for your comment. That was a mistake that I made (and now fixed). However, I still want to have another titlespacing on even and odd pages.

Comment: on headings that have a forced page break like chapters you can use `\ifodd\value{page} 5pt\else 10pt\fi` on headings that do not force a page break (like sections usually) it's not so easy as the heading is set before the page is known.